# Cant Run or Debug php application in eclipse using xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

Previously, i was able to set up the php debugging using xdebug and eclipse(say box1). But on a new machine(say box2) this is not at all working. I have been through a lot of forums and threads but dint find the solution to resolve my problem. Detail of the problem is:

I am using :
eclipse helios 32 bit, 
WAMP 32 bit,
on my 64 bit win7 box. (same setup on box1 except box1 has win8 64 bit). On box2, i have successfully configured the xdebug as everything seems ok on the phpinfo() page(compared with the one on box1). checked all the setting in php.ini on both boxes, no difference.

Now, i setup the Debug As configuration on box2 (similar as on box1) and when i choose to debug eclipse on box2, eclipse does not do anything, while on box1 it start the debugging and launch the application in browser.

May be i am making some silly mistake, coz i have setup this once before as mentioned on box1.
But this time i am not having any luck.
Can you guys help please? i have been stuck here for 3 days now. :(

let me know if you need any more info.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Solved]
I have downloaded a new version of eclipse Luna for PHP from the official website, and things are working fine.
Not Sure what was wrong with the eclipse Helios but for now my trouble is over.

Happy PHP.

Thanks.